# Spring Dependency injection injection level

Tags: spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am New At Spring.Recently I am doing my major project on Fuzzy based Decision Support System.It is web based application.I am using various spring frameworks in my project like spring security ,springjdbc,and dependency injection and Finally spring mvc.
***My quesation is to what level Dependency injection can be done..?***
I want to elaborate it...
Suppose i have class  defines as request scope bean in my spring configuration file .I have Singleton DAOImPl bean with of  Dependency to above request scope bean.Finally DAOImPl bean is autowired to my singleton Controller.With this set up my App works perfectly fine.Here Dependency is injected upto 2 level first request scope bean to DaoIMPL beans and daoIMPL bean to controller.
In the same pattern to what level dependency can be injected in spring web.I m talking about inejcting session and scope beans to ohter scope bean on spring.
Help is Really appricated.

Comment: My question is how many layers as such you have? A normal Spring-MVC application has service, dao layers for which you can use injection, which others are there is what I am curios now..

Comment: service layer can also use other suporting class functionality to do its job in  such case supporting class bean have to be autowird to service class ,and service class to Doa impl class and finally Doaimple class to controller.is not it

Comment: As long as you don't create circular references, I don't believe there is any problem...You can go how much ever levels you want.

Comment: Firstly What is Circular references..?

Comment: A says connect me to B when you are loading, B says connect me to C when you are loading and finally C says connect me to A when you are loading, but A is waiting to be connected to B and to C, so it creates a loop(Deadlock). In Spring terms, a Circular reference.

Comment: What if this happens A says connect me to B while B is loading And C says connect me to B While C is loading .Where B has request or session scope life time

Comment: It does not matter, this happens when the application is getting compiled/loaded and you are autowiring, you will get an error.

Comment: so you mean that i can inject a request bean to my daoimpl class as well as my controller class and also daoimpl class bean  to my controller class without myoriginal issue and this Circular reference issue

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then when your DAOImpl will inject to your service layer or controller..then you will have a circular reference.

Comment: i have this case  A inject to B. also A injected to C andB injected to C will tere be circular refrecne problem if A is request scope

Comment: I don'f think with this case there will not be circular deoendency. because only thing dependency is request scope bean class  which does not have any autowired dependency to classes which have have this request scope class dependency.

Comment: Like I said, if you are autowiring or injecting in some other manner, then you will have it...